# IE 8,9 на стероидах?

Tags: internet-explorer

На работе старая система с кучей чудес, завязанных на ActiveX. Соотвественно, в других браузерах работать не хочет. Но больше всего удручает то, что стоит какая то совместимость, чуть ли не под ие 6\7. В своих страницах (отображаются во фрейме) еще спасала строка

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

и 9 ослик хоть немного оживал.
Но вот решил использовать кое-что новое и совершенно непонятную реакцию получил.

Как можно "прокачать" IE, подгрузкой может каких js скриптов (про excanvas в курсе), или может плагин какой можно установить?

--

конкретно решил подгрузить страницу с yii (понимаю что тупо). и при выборе в фильтре страница пропадает. вообще не ожидал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использование полифилов (эмуляция новых технологий в старом браузере (де-факто это IE)) частично спасает ситуацию только при разработке.
Когда УЖЕ написана куча старого хлама, то тут уже нужен полифил наоборот - эмуляция старого браузера в новых, а такого я никогда не видел, да и вряд ли существует такое.
В осле есть режим совместимости - переключаешь и "браузер" прикидыватся старой версией.

Comment: не нужно "тупить" норм браузеры. на этом сайте 70% на другом браузере кроме IE не сработают. но даже IE 9 ведет себя как кретин из-за режима совместимости